# Is there a way to replace the same string across multiple anki cards?

Tags: sqlite, anki

I'm a fan of the dark theme but I'm a little bothered by the lack of contrast with the dark blue color in several of my cards.

I have many cards created years ago where I used the blue color to highlight some of the content and it worked well.
But now, with the dark theme, the contrast of the background with the blue is horrible and uncomfortable on the eye.

as I have many cards, I would like to know if there is a way to perform the same replacement on multiple cards?

I managed to change the blue color on the hidden word type cards but I still have a lot of blue words scattered around the deck.

Looking at the source code for the cards, I realized that I needed to replace all occurrences of

```
color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
```

for something like

```
color: rgb(255, 85, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I found to replace text on multiple cards was by operating directly on the sqlite database.

The step by step was more or less this:

1. Download and install sqlite database reader. Like this [one](https://sqlitebrowser.org/).
2. Locate the folder on is anki's sqlite file. On windows, just go to **%APPDATA%\Anki2** and locate the **collection.anki2** file inside some subfolder. Instructions for other platforms are [here](https://docs.ankiweb.net/files.html).
3. Close **anki** and make a backup copy of collection.anki2 in case something goes wrong.
4. Open **collections.anki2** in the sqlite database reader application and then run the sql commands to perform the text replacements. For example, for color changes described in the question I run the following SQL codes:

UPDATE notes SET flds = replace( flds 'color: rgb(0, 0, 255);', 'color: rgb(255, 85, 0);');

UPDATE notes SET sfld = replace( sfld 'color: rgb(0, 0, 255);', 'color: rgb(255, 85, 0);');

explaining the command references:

- **notes** is the table that holds the texts of all the cards
- **flds** is the column that holds the text on the front of each card  is the
- **sfld** column that contains the text on the back of each card

Comment: Wow this is **way** overkill. Besides, you shouldn't access Anki's database: that's implementation details. The proper way is simply to use the [*Find and Replace*](https://docs.ankiweb.net/browsing.html#find-and-replace) feature.